# application.js is not found in test mode of rails application which use poltergeist and capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

i am trying to run a feature spec with poltergeist and capybara.i see
application javascript is not found error

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_selector = :css
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|    
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :window_size => [1920, 1080], :phantomjs_logger => nil, :js_errors => false)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your asset pipeline isn't working correctly in your test environment.  This would have nothing to do with Capybara or your driver configuration.  Check your config/environements/test.rb to make sure you haven't turned off serving of assets, and try deleting everything in public/assets to see if that will force the tests to rebuild the required assets.

Comment: Thanks for the response, i still see the same issue after deleting assets.